# swiperjs es module build doesn't work in IE11 browser

Tags: babeljs, webpack-4, swiper.js, dom7

I am using `webpack` with `babel` to transpile modules and after adding `swiper` npm package to the build, IE11 browser stopped working because `dom7` dependency is not transpiled properly. This is pointed out on the `swiper's` [get started](https://swiperjs.com/get-started/) page, however it is not clear what has to be done to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After couple days of research and multiple attempts, I've finally got it working.

**Important** thing to note is that you must use `babel.config.js` instead of `.babelrc` so that `node_modules` could be included into build.

The final configuration:

`babel.config.js` (relevant section only):

```
module.exports = {
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/env", {
      "targets": {
        "ie": "11"
      }
    }],...
```

`webpack.config.js` (relevant section only):

```
test: /\.js$/,
exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(swiper|dom7)\/).*/,
rules: [
   {
     use: [{
       loader: 'babel-loader',
       options: {
         cacheDirectory: true,
         babelrc: false,
         rootMode: 'upward'
       }
     }]
   }
 ]
```

Here is the article which got me to the right direction (see comment from RyanGosden) - https://www.bountysource.com/issues/79144083-not-working-in-ie11

Hope that helps other people to save some time!

Answer (score 1):

Update in 2022:

Previous answer was correct, but swiper 7 adds a new esm dependency named ssr-window. So it needs to be added as below:

*webpack.config.js* (relevant section only):

```
test: /\.js$/,
exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(swiper|dom7|ssr-window)\/).*/,
rules: [
   {
     use: [{
       loader: 'babel-loader',
       options: {
         cacheDirectory: true,
         babelrc: false,
         rootMode: 'upward'
       }
     }]
   }
 ]
```